# Causal-net category and poset category

Tags: ct.category-theory, order-theory, posets

Order is a fundamental mathematical structure. There are two natural ways to represent order structures, by posets and by causal-nets (acyclic directed graph). How can we compare these two ways, and which way would be more fundamental the other one?

To be more precise, I introduce causal-net category in https://arxiv.org/abs/2201.08963, whose objects are causal-nets and morphisms are functors between the path categories of causal-nets. This category is natural, but unlike the poset category, as far as I know, it is rarely studied. So I wonder if there are any natural connections between causal-net category and poset category?

Comment: It's not really clear what you're looking for. I think you'll get more answers if you ask a more focused, targeted question.

Comment: @Tim Campion My question is what is the connection between causal-net category and poset category, for example,  are there an adjunction between them?